Foxhunt transmitter for 33cm?
I would like to find an off-the-shelf foxhunt transmitter for the 902-928 band, similar to what Byonics does for the 2m band. Simple on-off keying and CWID is all that I must have, audio tone generation would be a plus.
I've looked at lots of LORA etc radios, and after a lot of digging it does not seem that the LORA chipsets can be talked into just raising and dropping a carrier.
I might have to resort to using some kind of commercial HT, but I really don't want to deal with the programming/tuning issues, plus have to build some controller on top of that.
This is already a project, I don't really want a project on a project on a project.


and after a lot of digging it does not seem that the LORA chipsets can be talked into just raising and dropping a carrier.

I don't believe that's true. The SX1261/SX1262 datasheet lists a command SetTxContinuousWave that simply generates carrier at the configured center frequency and output power (all modulation settings are ignored). You can turn the carrier off again using SetRx.
The SX1276/1277/1278/1279 don't appear to have that command, but they do have an "OOK" (on/off keying) packet format, and I suspect that you could get those chips to behave as a CW beacon by setting the modem to OOK, whitening off, CRC off, and using the "continuous mode" or the "unlimited length packet format".

I'm more than willing to be wrong! :)

Ok, I see that in the data sheet.  Values to be written to a command register somewhere?   I have a LoRa library in my sketch, hopefully I can figure out how to write those values.
The modules I have are Heltec V3 with the SX1262.  Not worrying about working the display at this point.

@user103218 yes. If you provide a link to the library you're using I can help look and see if there's a way to send the command.

https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa

Here's what I have, not working of course.
void SetTxContinuousWave(){
// 0x0D is "write register"
LoRa.write(0x83FFFFFF); // Send 0x83 to put the chip in transmit mode (FFFFFF is the timeout value)
LoRa.write(0xD1);      // Send 0xD1 to Turn carrier on.
}
void SetRx(){
LoRa.write(0x82FFFFFF);      // Send 0x82 to Turn carrier off (FFFFFF is the timeout value)
}

@user103218 that library looks like it's for the SX127x chips, not SX126x.

Ok, that could be a problem.  :)   I'll go dig.

https://github.com/beegee-tokyo/SX126x-Arduino

@user103218 there you go. It looks a little complicated to get started with, but it has a Radio.SetTxContinuousWave() method :)

Just as a remark from a few feet above this situation: most radio ICs have a mode where they emit a tone. Why? It makes no sense for a LoRa device to emit an unmodulated carrier! It's for testing, and certification. At the end of your factory, you want to be sure that your devices oscillators and amplifiers work within nominal ranges. Emitting a known tone: perfect for that! If the device fails that, no need for further testing. And for certification, there's some test procedures that demand a device to be configured to emit a single tone. And that tone then needs to have less than a specified

… power. That makes absolutely no sense for a device that would never emit a tone in real operation, but as someone who needs to get your device certified by a nation's standards to sell it in that nation's market, you better implement a single-tone mode in your spread-spectrum transmitter, with low output power; you won't win anything trying to argue with the authorities there.

"Tone" here can be misleading.  "Continuous unmodulated carrier" is the thing, and the power needs to be equal to the full output power of the device.  There might be some use for adjustable power.

I know you don't want yet another project, but...
My personal plan for a low cost 33 / 23 cm fox (for scout foxhunting games) is to use any random square wave source, say a Si5351, and follow it with a 915 MHz SAW filter, to produce only one of the harmonics. The SAW is cheap and effective. I've looked at the clock chip harmonics, it will give you about 1 mW at 915 or 1295 MHz. So two $5 aliex modules and an Arduino or something for keying.
Perhaps an NRF905 can produce CW and be keyed, I haven't tried this, and I suspect most ISM band transmitters will default to some sort of frequency hopping.
For more power you're probably better off with a cheap HT.
